# Failing to pre-sign s3 url in Bahrain AWS region ONLY

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I've had some Python code that pre-signs AWS S3 URLs that have been working for years. We just added a new bucket in the Bahrain AWS data center. This location was disabled and required explicitly enabling that data center.

That all seemed fine. However, the resulting URL always gives me an `IllegalLocationConstraintException` and I believe `boto3` is generating the wrong domain name in the URL.

The error indicates that the request is sent to `us-east-1`. I know you have to specify the region, we have 8-10 regions we are using and they **all** are fine until this one.

The URL generated by `boto3.client('s3', ...).generate_presigned_url()` seems to give a URL for the us east S3. Given something like this:

```
region: me-south-1
bucket: bucket-name
key: full/path/to/file.txt
```

You would expect something like this for the signed URL:

```
https://bucket-name.s3.me-south-1.amazonaws.com/full/path/to/file.txt?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=AZIAJ4252S33LNN3Y14Q/20100504/me-south-1/s3/aws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20200504TA22522Z&X-Amz-Expires=3600&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Signature=1717275aff4af5fcff2f44f74615fadb5ba448eb83219c88f59d0792d4e44b8f
```

Notice the domain: `bucket-name.s3.me-south-1.amazonaws.com`

Yet, what we get from `boto3.client('s3', ...).generate_presigned_url()` is:

```
https://bucket-name.s3.amazonaws.com/full/path/to/file.txt?X-Amz-Algorithm=...
```

Notice that this resulting domain is: `s3.amazonaws.com`

Has anyone had issues with the newer s3 locations like this?

If it helps, the full error message we get back is:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Error>
   <Code>IllegalLocationConstraintException</Code>
   <Message>
   The me-south-1 location constraint is incompatible for the region specific endpoint this request was sent to.
   </Message>
</Error>
```

Comment: How old is your boto3 library?  This region was added in July 2019 and usually I need to update my libraries to add a new region.

Comment: Hi Stdunbar, it's the absolute latest. We use dependabot to keep it fresh weekly. I did have that thought too but it was a pretty new boto3. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try specifying `endpoint_url` in S3 client:

```
boto3.client('s3', endpoint_url='https://s3.me-south-1.amazonaws.com', region_name='me-south-1')
```

If you get the following error

```
The authorization mechanism you have provided is not supported. Please use AWS4-HMAC-SHA256.
```

specify `signature_version` too:

```
from botocore.client import Config
boto3.client('s3', config=Config(signature_version='s3v4'), endpoint_url='https://s3.me-south-1.amazonaws.com', region_name='me-south-1')
```

I have tried and it works for me ◡̈

Comment: Buckets in AWS regions that were launched after March 20, 2019 do not work with `bucket.s3.amazonaws.com` URLs. See [Legacy Global Endpoint](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/VirtualHosting.html#VirtualHostingBackwardsCompatibility) for an explanation (sort of).

Comment: This is exactly the right answer Jellycsc. I managed to rewrite a bunch of S3 work with this and it's running on 11 AWS data centers now. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue in af-south-1 and this is workaround, which works for me:

```py
s3 = boto3.client('s3', region_name='af-south-1')
endpointUrl = s3.meta.endpoint_url
s3 = boto3.client('s3', endpoint_url=endpointUrl, region_name='af-south-1')
```

Yes, as you can see, boto3 S3 client object knows the proper URL but does not use it.

Of course it will be better to [fix it in boto3](https://github.com/boto/boto3/issues/3015).

Comment: Had the same issue for `eu-south-1`; this solution works, and it's insulting. :')